# how do I make this gradient transparent?

Tags: html, css

I am using this code to add a gradient behind my menus to make them pop more.

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)));
```

I need the background of my web page to be transparent (so I can see stuff behind it). How do I use this to keep the emphasis around my menus, but make it so I can still see content behind it?

Comment: you should first test with nowdays syntax without vendor prefix, unless you are running an old browser ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current syntaxes are:

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65));
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65));
```

EG.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65));
}
```

The rest of your question isn't quite as...ahem, clear.

Comment: awesome example! I appreciate it! To clear up the rest of the question is basically as so... Imagine at the bottom of your html page that you just made, having white menus. Would this allow you to replace "lightblue" with transparent and see anything going on behind the app?

Comment: It sounds like you need an *overlay*...but without knowing exactly what it is you are trying to do it's hard to comment further. Sounds like something for a NEW question.